# Concise AWK for pattern matching a column while keeping header for each file specified

Tags: awk

I am doing work on a few files and they look something like this

file1.txt

```
CHROM START END CLASS
1 234 456 ADD
3 345 5678 COV
4 2588 92498 COV
5 9823 10000 ADD
```

file2.txt

```
CHROM START END CLASS
5 85345 9398595 ADD
11 8431 98345 COV
19 127 924 ADD
13 8693 10000 ADD
```

What I am trying to do is to use AWK to:

1. Extract lines with the 4th column having the pattern "ADD"
2. Keep the header, a.k.a the first line
3. Do this for each file specified
4. If possible, I would like to keep the code clean and precise. I would like to see if there is a way to do this without wrapping the AWK command in a BASH for loop. I hope that makes sense :)

The DESIRED final result would look like this

file1.txt.add

```
CHROM START END CLASS
1 234 456 ADD
5 9823 10000 ADD
```

file2.txt.add

```
CHROM START END CLASS
5 85345 9398595 ADD
19 127 924 ADD
13 8693 10000 ADD
```

After looking up the AWK documents and searching around stackoverflow on how to do this, this is the code I have so far,

`awk 'NR==1 {print>FILENAME".add"}; NR > 1 && $4~/ADD/ {print>FILENAME".add"}; ' file*.txt`

I believe that I am REALLY CLOSE. My ONLY problem is that this code only keeps the header for the 1st file. It, however, doesn't keep the header for the 2nd file. It looks like this:

file1.txt.add

```
CHROM START END CLASS
1 234 456 ADD
5 9823 10000 ADD
```

file2.txt.add

```
5 85345 9398595 ADD
19 127 924 ADD
13 8693 10000 ADD
```

I am not sure why it behaves like this and don't quite know where to start debugging this. If I could get some insight on this, it would be a great help.

P.S The reason why I am doing this is because I really like AWK and I would love to get better at it. I figured that I could save some times and just do this in Python, but if I do it that way I will never get better at AWK. So this is kind of like a challenge for me, but I am now stuck, haha :)

Comment: Then remove the `bash` tag if it is only `awk` you're after.

Comment: I apologize, I removed it. I'm still new in term of posting questions. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. You need not to run a bash loop to run `awk` code in it, `awk` is very much capable to read all the files in a single shot by itself. Following code will create output file names with eg--> `file1.txt.add` and only .txt format files are being passed as an input to awk program here.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  close(outFile)
  outFile=FILENAME".add"
  print > (outFile)
  next
}
$NF=="ADD"{
  print > (outFile)
}
' *.txt
```

***OR***

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  close(outFile)
  outFile=FILENAME".add"
}
FNR==1 || $NF=="ADD"{
  print > (outFile)
}
' *.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                       ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==1{                     ##Checking condition if this is first line of each file then do following.
  close(outFile)            ##Closing output file to avoid "too many files" error.
  outFile=FILENAME".add"    ##Creating variable which has output file name in it.
  print > (outFile)         ##Printing current line here.
  next                      ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
$NF=="ADD"{                 ##Checking condition if last field is ADD then do following.
  print > (outFile)         ##Printing current line to output file.
}
' *.txt                     ##Passing all .txt files to awk program as an input.
```

Comment: I just tested it it and it worked wonders. Thank you for the code and the code comments. That helped my understanding a lot!!!

Comment: @NhatDuong,your welcome cheers and happy learning on this great forum